# How to initialise data with 0 while reallocating in C?

Tags: c

I have an array of `char`, and want to dynamically allocate it while initialising each element with `0`.

For the first time, I can do this with `calloc()`, but for next times, I will be forced to use `realloc()`, which of course does not initialise the data.

Note that I only want to initialise those amounts of bytes which have been reallocated.

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `memset` is one way.

Comment: use any function that can initialize memory : `memset`, `bzero`, etc.